# Outlook 2007 - incomplete date in replies

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

When replying to (or forwarding) an email, the date from the header of the original email is not completely carried over to the quoted text.

[image]

In the attached example it says "Sent: Tuesday, December 2010 4:47 PM" (no day number), but should say: "Sent: Tuesday, December **28,** 2010 4:47 PM" (emphasis mine). Any ideas how to fix? (OS is Windows XP SP3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in your regional settings

Control panel >> Clock, Language & Region >> Change the Date or Time number format >> Customize this format... >> Date tab

In the "Long date" box, make sure there are less than 3 "d"s or you will  only see the day and not the date in your replies.